# Calculate area of circle by summing infinitesimal rectangles [Solved by me]

Tags: calculus

\begin{align}
dA & = 2RR\,dv = 2R^2\,dv \\[8pt]
A & = \int_0^\pi 2R^2\,dv \\[8pt]
\text{arclength} & = R\,dv
\end{align}

[image]

Area of a circle with radius $R$ is $\pi R^2$.

I am trying to discover new correct methods for finding the area of a circle. Using rectangles is not something new per say, but summing infinitesimal rectangles going through the center with the angle as a parameter I have not seen before. Anyway, I have encountered a problem:

Let $dA$ be the infinitesimal rectangle of width $R\,dv$ and length $2R$. As seen in the picture, the position of the rectangle is determined by the angle $V$. If, for example, $V=0$ the rectangle will be positioned "horisontal", and if $V=\frac{\pi}{2}$ the rectangle will be positioned "vertical".

It does seem logical to me that if we add all the rectangles going from $V: 0$ to $\pi$ the sum will be the area of the circle. But we get $2\pi R^2$, double the area, why?

**Update:**
WOW! I have not been given the reason for why my method failed, but I figured it out myself! So by drawing the rectangle corresponding to $v$ and $v+dv$  I saw and realized that they overlapped each other, which is bad if we want the exact result. But by symmetry I found that the formed overlap is a parallelogram with $base=R$ and $height=R$, thus every overlap is worth $Area= base*height = R^2$. Subtracting this in the final integral gives us A $= \int_0^\pi 2R^2 - R^2\,dv = \pi R^2$

**Update2**

I may be right for the wrong reasons here. The area of the overlap can't possible be $R^2$, that seems too large considering that the area of the rectangle itself is smaller than that when dv is infinitesmal.

[image]

Comment: You can't place a rectangle of length $2R$ inside a circle of radius $R$, the width would have to be $0$

Comment: @gd1035 If the width is infinitesimal, we can? This is just riemann integration right?

Comment: @SwedeGustaf Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

The length of the red line parallel to the diameter is $2R\cos v.$

Its distance from that diameter is $R\sin v.$ Therefore its infinitesimal change is $R\cos v \,dv.$

And $v$ needs to go from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2,$ for reasons that should be apparent from the picture.

So the area is $\displaystyle \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} 2R^2 \cos^2 v\, dv. $

Comment: Nice work. The way your method works is not obvious at first glance. Please tell me if I am wrong, but I imagine your method as rectangles of width $2R\cos(v)$ and height $R\cos(v)dv$ obviously summed along the y-axis (from -R to R).

Comment: @Adam : Correct. $\qquad$

Comment: **Update:**
WOW! I have not been given the reason for why my method failed, but I figured it out myself! So by drawing the rectangle corresponding to v and v+dv  I saw and realized that they overlapped each other, which is bad if we want the exact result. But by symmetry I found that the formed overlap is a parallelogram with base=R and height=R, thus every overlap is worth Area= base*height = R^2. Subtracting this in the final integral gives us A $= \int_0^\pi 2R^2 - R^2\,dv$

Answer (score 1):

It is not a correct set up to calculate the area since the width of the rectangle varies with $v$.

As an alternative we can use

$$A=2\int_0^R 2\sqrt{R^2-y^2}\,dy$$

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why the width $=Rdv$ would vary more than your $dy$ ? $R$ is a constant, I should add.

Comment: @Adam In mine set up the area of the rectangle is $$dA=w\cdot dh=2\sqrt{R^2-y^2}\cdot dy$$ and the width varies with $y$. In your set up the witdh is constant and equal to $2R$.

Comment: Yes in my set up the width is constant because I am rotating the rectangles of infinitesimal height $Rdv$ around the center and adding their respective area. In other words, the rectangle is rotating as we change the angle $V$. However, I have not derived this method rigorously so I am not surprised the method is failing.

Comment: @Adam Then is better to rotate the triangles and obtain $$\int_0^{\pi} 2\cdot \frac12 R\cdot R dv=\pi R^2$$

Comment: **Update:**
WOW! I have not been given the reason for why my method failed, but I figured it out myself! So by drawing the rectangle corresponding with v and v+dv  I saw and realized that they overlapped each other, which is bad if we want the exact result. But by symmetry I found that the formed overlap is a parallelogram with base=R and height=R, thus every overlap is worth Area= base*height = R^2. Subtracting this in the final integral gives us A $= \int_0^\pi 2R^2 - R^2\,dv$

Comment: @Adam This way it is not completely clear to me as set up but it is equivalent to consider the triangles, that is half area of the rectangle.